# xmllint - unable to read special characters

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xpath, xmllint

On the bash shell prompt i want to run xmllint to get data from a xml file.  Lets look at a file in which i have no issues:

behold the fruits.xml file:

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
  <string name="mykey">grapes</string>
</map>
```

and this is me using xmllint to get the value "grapes" from fruits.xml

```
xmllint --xpath "string(/map/string[@name = 'mykey'])" fruits.xml
```

and i get the output of the following:

```
$ grapes
```

great i got the value, but this is not the actual key i need to use. "mykey" should be "c1:fruits_id-%1$s"

now when i change the "mykey" value in the fruits.xml file to another value i am unable to get any return value from xmllint:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
  <string name="c1:fruits_id-%1$s">grapes</string>
</map>


xmllint --xpath "string(/map/string[@name = 'c1:fruits_id-%1$s'])" fruits.xml
```

the above command returns nothing.  All im doing is changing the key name and now it wont work. can someone help ?

Comment: Is your shell perhaps replacing `$s` with something else (e.g. nothing)?

Comment: bingo you got it.   i had to do \$s to get it to work. post an official answer  if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The XML document you show does not have the `c1:` in front of the attribute value - a typo, I guess?)

If you use `$` in a shell command, it is interpreted as a variable and variable interpolation kicks in. Because the variable does not exist, it is replaced with nothing. You can test this by changing your XML document to

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
  <string name="c1:fruits_id-%1">grapes</string>
</map>
```

The only change is that the two characters `$s` are deleted. Now the path expression finds the string:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "string(/map/string[@name = 'c1:fruits_id-%1$s'])" fruit.xml
grapes
```

---

Either escape the character as `\$` as Biffen has already suggested:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "string(/map/string[@name = 'c1:fruits_id-%1\$s'])" fruit.xml
grapes
```

or, equally easy, swap the quotes:

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(/map/string[@name = "c1:fruits_id-%1$s"])' fruit.xml
grapes
```

There is no variable interpolation for strings that are delimited by single quotes, even if there are double quotes inside them (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13010/dollar-sign-interpolation-inside-quotes-in-bash)).